# Add ValidationAttribute on server side validation at runtime depending on another container property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

There is a class (stripped down version):

```
public class Parameter
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have a dictionary of Parameters, they get rendered like this:

```
<input ... name="Parameters[3].Key" type="hidden" value="UniqueParamName" />
<input ... name="Parameters[3].Value.Id" type="hidden" value="395816ad-dfde-11e1-8c36-848f69f05f09" />
<input ... name="Parameters[3].Value.Value" type="text" value="75" />
```

Validation rules are going to be set by user though some GUI and stored in a database.
I want to get `ValidationAttribute`s from a database by `Parameter.Id` for current `Parameter.Value`, but I can't see any way of doing it. 
I also tried to add attributes in `ModelMetadataProvider.CreateMetadata`, where container can be accessed through some [nasty] reflection, but the "Id" has not yet been assigned when metadata is being created for the "Value" (anyway, it's not reliable).
Maybe I'm overcomplicating the whole thing, I just want to stick to the built-in validation.

```
public class ExtendedValidationProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(
        ModelMetadata metadata, 
        ControllerContext context, 
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        if (metadata.ContainerType == typeof(Parameter) 
            && metadata.PropertyName == "Value")
        {
            Guid parameterId = <some magic code>;
            IEnumerable<Attribute> validationAttributes 
                = db.GetValidationAttributesByParameterId(parameterId);
            return base.GetValidators(metadata, context, validationAttributes);
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidator>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I can set container in a custom ModelMetadataProvider like this:

```
public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForProperty(Func<object> modelAccessor,
    Type containerType, string propertyName)
{
    var metadata = _InnerProvider.GetMetadataForProperty(modelAccessor, containerType, propertyName);
    if (containerType == typeof(Parameter) 
        && !metadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("container"))
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["container"] = GetContainer(modelAccessor);
    }

    return metadata;
}
```

`GetContainer` is a method using that [nasty] reflection (compiled and cached expression, actually).

Finally, there is no magic code on the validation provider's side:

```
public class ExtendedValidationProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(
        ModelMetadata metadata, 
        ControllerContext context, 
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        if (metadata.ContainerType == typeof(Parameter) 
            && metadata.PropertyName == "Value")
        {
            Guid parameterId = ((Parameter)metadata.AdditionalValues["container"]).Id;
            IEnumerable<Attribute> validationAttributes 
                = db.GetValidationAttributesByParameterId(parameterId);
            return base.GetValidators(metadata, context, validationAttributes);
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidator>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should be using Model Validation.  Model Validation will verify against your model and the rules applied with the validation attributes defined on the model.

```
public class MyModel
{
     // This model uses model validation

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "FirstName is a required field.")]
     [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Your FirstName can not exceed 50 characters.")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "LastName is a required field.")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This sets up your model for validation. Then in your controller/action you will need to verify your ModelState using **ModelState.IsValid**.  You can do some custom "verifying" in  your controller as well and add custom errors by using **AddModelError** of the **ModelState**.

If you wanted to take it a step further and create your own validation attribute, then all you need to do is create a new class that is inherited from the **ValidationAttribute** class.  This would allow you to verify against your own values that might be in the DAL layer or against another value that was bound to your model.

Using model validation also sets you up nicely (and easily) if you needed to use globalization as there are attributes available that will allow you to select a resource file with your resource strings for various languages that you might have defined.

I'm doing this from memory, but this should lead you in the right direction to use the built-in features of MVC3 and take advantage of model binding and model states.

HTH

Comment: My validation rules are to be set through the user interface and later loaded from database, this is why I titled this question with words "at runtime". Guess I should state it clearer.

Comment: Yes, this can still apply.  You would still write a ValidationAttribute that would do your custom validation rule lookups (from database, etc.) and then place this custom attribute on your model.

Comment: I can't place it upon my model, because what you suggest is on per type basis and I need it different on every instance of 'Parameter'